# Filter datatable between two dates

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, datatable

I have a column within my database called "Month". What i want to do is filter the table between two months. Example of this is March - June. I have code which works BUT only works alphabetically

```
string strquery = "select * from tbl_DR_data ";
string strq2 = "where";

if (DropDownList6.SelectedItem.Text != "All" && DropDownList8.SelectedItem.Text != "All") {
    string month1 = DropDownList6.SelectedItem.Text.ToString();
    string month2 = DropDownList8.SelectedItem.Text.ToString();
    strq2 = strq2 + "[Month] BETWEEN'" + month1 + "'AND'" + month2 + "'";
}
```

When `DropDownList6 = March` and `DropDownList8 = June`. Nothing appears in the gridview which im binding BUT if the swap them around so DDL6= June and DDL8 = March it works :S

Is there a work around so that i can have the months ordered in how the months are meant to be instead of being alphabetical

Comment: what is the datatype of "Month" column in your DB??

Comment: This seems like the incorrect design. You should have used an integer to represent the month number.

Comment: @watraplion is it a varchar(25). Also im not the one who has created the data base at all

Comment: You could get around this by using something like `CASE WHEN Month='Jan' THEN 1 WHEN Month='Feb' THEN 2 etc.` wherever you have a month specified as a character string. Mind you, it'll be a lot of typing :-)

Comment: @astander thats what im thinking at the moment just because it will be alot better

Answer (score 1):

why are you really storing months as strings in the database?, if you follow that path, trust me you are even going to encounter much more serious problems down the road & they will be a hell to debug. You can always get the month part from any date or dateTime column value.

Answer (score 0):

try this code, Hope this what you expected

```
SET @FromMonth = 'March'
SET @ToMonth = 'June'
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  tbl_DR_data
WHERE
   DATEPART(mm,CAST([Month]+ ' 1900' AS DATETIME)) >= DATEPART(mm,CAST(@FromMonth+ ' 1900' AS DATETIME))
   AND DATEPART(mm,CAST([Month]+ ' 1900' AS DATETIME)) <= DATEPART(mm,CAST(@ToMonth+ ' 1900' AS DATETIME))
```

Answer (score 0):

[This is the MSDN Syntax for BETWEEN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx)

```
test_expression [ NOT ] BETWEEN begin_expression AND end_expression
```

Why no results when `When DropDownList6 = March and DropDownList8 = June`?

With above values, your query becomes like

```
[Month] BETWEEN 'March' AND 'June'
```

Unfortunately, when you are filtering using **`BETWEEN, begin_expression should be less than or equal to end_expression`**. In your case, since you have stored months (names) as string in the database, **`March comes after June in alphabetical order`** and so above condition returns false and no results.

[This is a fiddle example same as yours with no results.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3f197/2)

You can get the month from a date/datetime field using various methods. In sql server, you can use;

```
//Month NUMBER
month(datefield) as month_Number 
//Month NAME
datename(month,datefield) as month_Name
```

Just to give you worst side of your design. **[Just check the results of](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8ad7b/5)**  filtering by `where month between 'april' and 'may'`.

Your results include: `August, December, February, January, July, June, March`

**Solution:**

For the time since you don't have full date, I guess it would be better to update your database filed as below and change the datatype of [month] to int type;

```
update yourTable
set [month] = case [month] when 'January' then 1
                           when 'February' then 2
                           ...
                           when 'December' then 12 end
```

Now change the data type of [month] to int type and then pass the month number from the code as

```
[month] BETWEEN 3 and 6
```

Also, try to avoid key words such as `Month` for field names.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your DB design is or even what the Month Fields data-type is, I agree with other first & foremost that this is not a good design as i cant think of a scenario where i can search only based on month. This should be a complete date fields.

It can give us better idea if you give us very brief about this functionality like where you want to use it & purpose.

Please don't take me as a critic... more details about your project can help us better understand & recommend solution. May be i am wrong as i may have not understand your question.

You can use nice solution given but think for the road ahead..